# Set IIS to run with environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, iis, debug

I'm trying to run IIS with the `COMPLUS_ZapDisable` environment variable set to 1.  Per [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-disable-optimizations-when-debugging-reference-source.aspx) (which shows how to do it for regular exes), I hope this will allow me to load non-optimized versions of the .NET Framework so that I can step through some stuff while debugging and actually read the values of variables.

I'm not certain that setting this environment variable for w3wp.exe is actually the solution I'm looking for, as in the link, I was setting it specifically for Visual Studio, as opposed to whatever program I'm debugging.

Any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Setting a `COMPLUS_ZapDisable` **global** environment variable and restarting IIS will work, however it will affect all managed process in your system.

You could also try setting the AppPool identity to a local user, configure it to load the user profile, and set the environment variable for that user.